# Permutation yielding the largest value of $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{p(k)}$ and one yielding the smallest

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In Concrete Mathematics it is stated that:

> In general, if $a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_n$ and if $p$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, it's not difficult to prove that the largest value of $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{p(k)}$ occurs when $b_{p(1)}\leq \cdots\leq b_{p(n)}$ and the smallest value occurs when $b_{p(1)}\geq\cdots\geq b_{p(n)}$

while this seems intuitive to me I don't know how to formally prove it, i'd appreciate any help/hint on this

Comment: You said largest twice.

Comment: Are there any assumptions over the $a_i$? Are they, for instance, non-negative integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sum where $a_k$ is paired to $b_{p(k)}$ and $a_l$ to $b_{p(l)}$, where $l>k$. Now swap, i.e. pair $a_k$ to $b_{p(l)}$ and $a_l$ to $b_{p(k)}$. The sum varies by $(a_l-a_k)(b_{p(k)}-b_{p(l)})$, and becomes larger if $b_{p(k)}>b_{p(l)}$. After the swap, $b_{p(l)}>b_{p(k)}$.

You can repeat the sum-increasing swaps until $b$ is sorted increasingly.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If a permutation is not that one, you can interchange two elements and improve the sum (or at least make it not worse).